# How to Retrieve Specific Line of Code from a Dynamic Library Using Boost.Stacktrace in C++?

Tags: dll, module, boost-stacktrace

The program I've developed in C++ relies on several dynamic libraries, which have also been designed and developed modularly from a perspective of modularity. Now, if I use the Boost.Stacktrace library in the main program to obtain stack trace information when the program crashes, and the cause of the crash is due to code in one of the dynamic libraries, how can I output the specific line of code within the dynamic library? Currently, I can only pinpoint a specific function within the dynamic library.

The structure of my program has the following structure.

```
// Executable.cpp for Executable.exe
#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE
#include <modules/mouduleA.h>
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

void signal_handler(int signum)
{
  boost::stacktrace::stacktrace st;
  std::cerr << "Stacktrace for Exe: \n" << st << std::endl;

  boost::stacktrace::safe_dump_to("dump.core");

  exit(signum);
}

int main()
{
  signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler);
  
  foo(); // foo() is a callable function in moudleA

  return 0;
}

//================================================
// Module_A.h

void foo();

// Module_object.h
#define BOOST_STACKTRACE_USE_ADDR2LINE
#include <boost/stacktrace.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <csignal>

class Module_object {
  Module_object() {
    signal(SIGSEGV, signal_handler);
  }

  static void signal_handler(int signum) {
    boost::stacktrace::stacktrace st;
    std::cerr << "Stacktrace for module: \n" << st << std::endl;
  }
};

// Module_A.cpp for Module_A.dll
#include "Module_object.h"

static Module_object module;

void foo()
{
  int *p = nullptr;
  *p = 0; // trigger a segment fault purposely
}
```

The program only output the stacktrace information from Executable.exe, and I'd like to get stacktrace information from both Executable.exe and Module_A.dll. Any help will be grateful.